# singleInstance activity gets destroyed when I open other apps

Tags: android, android-activity

In my app, I have an activity with the following configuration.

```
 <activity
            android:name=".activities.CallScreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_call_screen"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:showOnLockScreen="true"
            android:showWhenLocked="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.SkyHighVocabulary"
            android:turnScreenOn="true"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"
            tools:targetApi="o_mr1" />
```

When this activity is running, If I go home and open any other app this activity gets destroyed. But all other activities are untouched. If I remove `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` it works fine. But I really need my activity to be singleInstance mode. Tried to use `largeHeap=true`, but that didn't help. How can I fix this?

Comment: what do you mean by "all other activities are untouched"? Where is `CallActivity` in the task stack when this happens? Why do you need this to be `singleInstance`?

Comment: Generally speaking, you should avoid using the special launch modes `singleInstance` and `singleTask`. And because you haven't set `taskAffinity` here, it probably isn't doing what you think it should do.

Comment: This activity is used for webRTC voice call using webView. When user clicks a button this activity is launched and the call will start. And it will show a progress notification. So that if the user navigate to any other app while on call, they can easily come back to calling screen by tapping the notification. When they click the notification I want my activity to persist its state without creating new instance. That's why I'm using single instance mode.

Comment: It isn't necessary to declare the `Activity` as singleInstance for this purpose. You can return to an existing task from a Notification without creating a new instance. This is standard Android behaviour.

Comment: But what do you mean by "all other activities are untouched"? What other activities? Does your app have other activities?

Comment: I'm assuming that `excludeFromRecents="true"` may be causing your problem. Since you exclude the task from appearing in the list of recent tasks, there is no way for the user to return to it. Since there is no way for the user to return to it, Android might as well kill it off.